# boolean type method - Area of a Triangle

Tags: java, methods, boolean, area

The triangle method (at the bottom) is supposed to return the String `"Invalid"` if the sum of the two smaller sides does not equal more than the larger side. I created a Boolean method (`isValid`) to test this, but am not sure how to test it within the triangle method. As you can see, I left the first `if` statement blank in the triangle method because I couldn't figure out what code to write that would achieve this. Thanks for any input.

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String inputOne;
    String inputTwo;
    String inputThree;
    double smallSide;
    double medSide;
    double largeSide;
    double sidea = 0;
    double sideb = 0;
    double sidec = 0;
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;

    inputOne = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter first side: ");
    smallSide = Integer.parseInt(inputOne);

    inputTwo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter second side: ");
    medSide = Integer.parseInt(inputTwo);

    inputThree = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter third side: ");
    largeSide = Integer.parseInt(inputThree);

    if (smallSide <= medSide && medSide <= largeSide)
    {
        sidea = smallSide;
        sideb = medSide;
        sidec = largeSide;
    } else if (medSide <= smallSide && smallSide <= largeSide)
    {
        sidea = medSide;
        sideb = smallSide;
        sidec = largeSide;

    } else if (smallSide <= largeSide && largeSide <= medSide)
    {
        sidea = smallSide;
        sideb = largeSide;
        sidec = medSide;
    } else if (medSide <= largeSide && largeSide <= smallSide)
    {
        sidea = medSide;
        sideb = largeSide;
        sidec = smallSide;
    } else if (largeSide <= smallSide && smallSide <= medSide)
    {
        sidea = largeSide;
        sideb = smallSide;
        sidec = medSide;
    } else if (largeSide <= medSide && medSide <= smallSide)
    {
        sidea = largeSide;
        sideb = medSide;
        sidec = smallSide;
    }
    a = sidec;
    b = sideb;
    c = sidea;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, triangle(a, b, c));

    if (isValid(sidea, sideb, sidec))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, area(sidea, sideb, sidec));
    }
}
public static boolean isValid(double sidea, double sideb, double sidec)
{
    double sum;

    sum = sidea + sideb;

    if (sum <= sidec)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else;
    return true;


}


 public static double area(double sidea, double sideb, double sidec)
 {
    double s;
    double next;
    double answer;

    s = (sidea + sideb + sidec) / 2; 
    next = (s * sidea) * (s * sideb) * (s * sidec);
    answer = s * next;
    return Math.sqrt(answer);



 }

 public static String triangle(double a, double b, double c)
 {
    if ()
        return "Invalid Triangle";
    else if (a == c)
        return "Equilateral";
    else if (a == b || b == c)
        return "Isosceles";
    else 
        return "Scalene";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be something like this?:

```
 if(isValid(a,b,c)==false)
```

or

```
 if(!isValid(a,b,c))
```

which basically is saying "if(is not valid)"

Comment: Thanks! Fixed it up... did not realize how the format looked until after I posted! :)

Comment: No problem. Weve all been there :)

Comment: That's it! I just had to switch a, b,  and c with c, b, and a because I put them in ascending order, so I was stuck on that for a bit. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, You just have write this algorithm on piece of paper, and then write code.
For example 
1. Find max side 
2. Count sum of others 
3. Compare rasults 
4. Show information
Then you understand what you have to write

Answer (score 0):

No need to apply so many if-else conditions to arrange the sides. You can omit them and can modify your `isValid` method as:

```
public static boolean isValid(double sidea, double sideb, double sidec) {
    if ((sidea + sideb > sidec) 
    && (sideb + sidec > sidea) 
    && (sidec + sidea > sideb)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is same as implementing the logic that in a triangle, sum of any two sides is always strictly greater than the third side.

Now, in the method triangle, the first if-statement could be written as:

```
if (!isValid(a,b,c)) {
    return "Invalid Triangle";
}
```